# Обновить переменную после отправки запроса ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Используется библиотека jquery.form для отправки данных без перезагрузки страницы, и вывод результата:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function()
{
    $('#contact-form').ajaxForm( {
        target: '#preview', 
        success: function() { 
            $('#formbox'); 
        } 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Но после отправки, переменнаю с капчей не обновляется, и выходит, то при попытке отправить данные еще раз, пишет что не верно введена капча, ибо значение ее не обновилось:

```
<?php include(CAPTCHA); ?>
          <span class="add-on"><?=$primer?></span>
```

Капча - примитивней не куда:

```
$a = rand(1,10);
$b = rand(1,10);
$primer = $a . '+' . $b . '= ';
$_SESSION['res'] = $a + $b;
```

а вот обработка капчи:

```
if (isset($_POST['captcha'])) { 
if ($_POST['captcha'] != $_SESSION['res']) {        
    $msg = 'Не верно сосчитал!'; 
    $_SESSION['mes'] = $msg;
    echo display_msg('Ошибка', 'alert-error', 'Не верно посчитал');;
    unset($_SESSION['mes']);
    exit;
  }
}
else {
    $msg = 'Капчу забыл!';
    echo display_msg('Ошибка', 'alert-error', 'Капчу забыл');
    exit;
    }
 unset($_SESSION['mes']);
```

как ее обновить после отправки?

Comment: в ответе ajax верните новые значения капчи и вставьте ее в форму

Comment: можно пример?